# SQL: find latest date when date is in varchar field and year is YY

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a database where dates are represented as strings in the format DD.MM.YY (don't ask). I wanted to find the latest date in the column by trying this:

```
select max(to_date(my_date, 'DD.MM.YY')) from my_table;
```

This gave a date from 1999 as the latest, but I know there are later dates in the column. I assume it's because the year is given as YY. How can I find the correct date?

Comment: Solutions for messy data are messy. Try with `to_date(my_date, 'DD.MM.RR')`

Comment: Y2K problem in 2018! Please convince the higher ups to get time to move to correct data types.

Comment: Look into the definition of to_date(), make sure it understands two-figure years for the input and make sure that the return type is date. If the to_date() function isn't doing that, fix it or write a new function that does.

Comment: @jchevali `to_date` has its own convenient web page ;) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html

Comment: Yes, it's a bloody mess, and yes, I'm going to make sure it'll get cleaned up when the whole thing gets migrated to a new platform next year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
select max(to_date(my_date, 'DD.MM.RR')) from my_table;
```

YY says, assume current century, so '99' turns into 2099.

```
SQL> select to_date('01.01.77', 'DD.MM.YY') from dual;
TO_DATE('01.01.77','DD.MM.YY')   
01-JAN-2077                      


SQL> 
SQL> select to_date('01.01.77', 'DD.MM.RR') from dual;
TO_DATE('01.01.77','DD.MM.RR')   
01-JAN-1977
```

If you want to make things easier for yourself, create a new table and fix the data type, or at least [add a Virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) to your existing table.

Comment: Cool. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: The only difficulty with the `RR` mask is that dates earlier than 1950 will be interpreted as being a century later. Not to take anything away from this great answer - just keep that caveat in mind. If you have dates earlier than 1950 in your table, you will have to write your own function to convert them.